# Maxscript Radiobutton and button comand

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I want to ask how does this work? in the "box" option then pressing the DO button will create a box.
I really appreciate any reply, thank you

rollout createobj "creatingobj" width:235
(
radiobuttons radmix "Create:" pos:[8,8] width:58 height:110 labels: #("box", "spehere", "cone", "cylinder", "geospehre", "plane") columns:1 offsets:#([0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]) align:#left
button btnmix "Do" pos:[136,16] width:94 height:104 align:#left
)
createDialog createobj

Answer (score 0):

It won't because there's no handler for the button. You should read the [Scripted Utilities and Rollout](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-B478B60B-B27D-4916-A07E-264818666080.htm,topicNumber=d30e625274) section of the reference and learn from that, there are many commented examples scattered throughout. Also, when posting code, use the Code button (or indent the codeblock manually). Here's a working code:

```
rollout createobj "creatingobj" width:235
(
    local items = #("box", "sphere", "cone", "cylinder", "geosphere", "plane")
    radiobuttons radmix "Create:" pos:[8,8] width:58 height:110 labels:items columns:1 align:#left
    button btnmix "Do" pos:[136,16] width:94 height:104 align:#left
    on btnmix pressed do (execute items[radmix.state])()
)
createDialog createobj
```